# Posting organized data using webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, url, asp.net-web-api

I need a help and stuck on this topic

I need to build a REST web api that takes as input parameter a set of organized data that I need to insert in the database.
The data will look like:

```
<JournalReport>
                            <JournalHeader>
                                            <ReportSequenceNumber>2012061401</ReportSequenceNumber>
                                            <ReportSequenceID>466</ReportSequenceID>
                                            <PrimaryReportPeriod>2012-06-14</PrimaryReportPeriod>
                                            <SecondaryReportPeriod>2012-06-14</SecondaryReportPeriod>
                                            <BeginDate>2012-06-14</BeginDate>
                                            <BeginTime>06:28:37</BeginTime>
                                            <EndDate>2012-06-14</EndDate>
                                            <EndTime>20:33:01</EndTime>
                            </JournalHeader>
                            <SaleEvent>
                                            <EventSequenceID>F40888</EventSequenceID>
                                            <TrainingModeFlag value="No" />
                                            <CashierID>001</CashierID>
                                            <RegisterID>0</RegisterID>
                                            <TillID>0</TillID>
                                            <OutsideSalesFlag value="No" />
                                            <TransactionID>00008</TransactionID>
                                            <EventStartDate>2012-06-14</EventStartDate>
                                            <EventStartTime>08:07:02</EventStartTime>
                                            <EventEndDate>2012-06-14</EventEndDate>
                                            <EventEndTime>08:07:02</EventEndTime>
                                            <BusinessDate>2012-06-14</BusinessDate>
                                            <ReceiptDate>2012-06-14</ReceiptDate>
                                            <ReceiptTime>08:07:02</ReceiptTime>
                                            <OfflineFlag value="Yes" />
                                            <SuspendFlag value="No" />
                           </SaleEvent>
```

Is it possible to handle? And in which way?

Comment: You will need to serialize the data. Just google "Xml to json" and you will see some sample output. You can deserialize json into class or xml for further process.

Comment: And how to send this data with url? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to post it. Just start with basics, create a example api and try sending some data in.

Comment: You'll need to go over [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding) docs, then [try](http://whathaveyoutried.com) it out. If you get stuck with specifics, that would be the time to post here. Your question is too broad to cover as it is (documentation is your best bet).

Comment: You do not need to convert it to JSON. While JSON is nicer than XML I recommend you work with what you already have since it's already been built. WebApi has out-of-the-box support for XML too. Don't reinvent the wheel.